# FreeBSD Nic Setup - Dual NICs with lagg

Tags: freebsd, ipv4, nic

I have a server running FreeBSD 9.0.  It has two NICs using the igb network drivers.  I was given a range of IPs, for example's sake I'm just going to make up some IP addresses, so let's say 192.168.0.24/29 with a broadcast ip of 192.168.0.31.  The gateway is at 192.168.0.25.

I have the `rc.conf` setup as follows:

```
defaultrouter="192.168.0.25"
hostname="web01.dev.example.com"
ifconfig_igb0="up"
ifconfig_igb1="up"
cloned_interfaces="lagg0"
ifconfig_lagg0="laggproto failover laggport igb0 laggport igb1 192.168.0.24/29"
```

When I enter `ifconfig` I get

```
 igb0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=401bb<RXCSUM, TXCSUM, VLAN_MTU, VLAN_HWTAGGING, JUMBO_MTU, VLAN_HWCSUM, TSO4, VLAN_HWTSO>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 XXXX::XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%igb0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD. IFDISABLED< AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
status: active

igb1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=401bb<RXCSUM, TXCSUM, VLAN_MTU, VLAN_HWTAGGING, JUMBO_MTU, VLAN_HWCSUM, TSO4, VLAN_HWTSO>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 XXXX::XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%igb0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD. IFDISABLED< AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
status: active

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
options = 600003<RXCSUM, TXCSUM, RXCSUM_IPV6, TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 XXXX:XXXXX prefixlen 62 scipeid 0x5
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000

lagg0 flags=8843<UP,BROADCST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=401bb<RXCSUM, TXCSUM, VLAN_MTU, VLAN_HWTAGGING, JUMBO_MTU, VLAN_HWCSUM, TSO4, VLAN_HWTSO>
ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
inet6: XXXX::XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%lagg0 prefixlen64 scopeid 0x6
inet 192.168.0.24 netmask 0xffffffff8 broadcast 192.168.0.31
nd6 options=29 <PERFORMNUM IFDISABLED AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
media: Ethernet autoselect
status: active
laggproto failover lagghash 12,13,14
laggport: igb1 flags=0<>
laggport: igb0 flags=5<MASTER,ACTIVE>
```

Which looks great, interfaces are up - and active.  I go to ping the gateway and get 100% packet loss.  I've tried service netif restart and it is pretty unremarkable, although as

```
ifconfig: create: bad value
```

shows up under lagg0, igb1 and igb0 and it shows `status: no carrier`

but if I type in ifconfig again after the restart it shows `status: active`, however still with no internet connection and still without the ability to ping the gateway.

I've referenced several sites, but very few reference the dual nic, lagg setup with ipv4 and ipv6 and I'm pretty much at a loss on how to go about fixing/troubleshooting the issue.  Any ideas on where to start would be great.

Comment: My working (FreeBSD 7) /etc/rc.conf has the same config and an additional `network_interfaces="bge0 bge1 lagg0"`. Did you edit that one out?

Comment: While it is rumoured to work with some equipment (I've never tried it myself), I would advise against using the network (first) address for your server. I would use 192.168.0.26/29. The easiest way to confirm if this is the problem (or a good place to start in any case) is to make sure everything works with one interface first then try lagg.

Comment: Hennes - it was missing I added it, unfortunately to no effect.  @Matt Thanks - I will modify the config with your suggestions and attempt to get the one interface running before going with lagg

Comment: Using Matt's advice I was able to get igb0 and igb1 working seperately ... I then went ahead and implemented lagg and everything appears to be functioning as it should, thanks again @Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Matt's advice I was able to get igb0 and igb1 working separately.
After confirming I could ping the gateway with each interface independently, I dropped the lagg interface back in, did a `service netif restart` followed by a `service routing restart`
and was able to ping the gateway again.

As far as to why they were not working together using the original configuration I couldn't say.  The only thing I could figure, is that both the igb0 and igb1 interfaces were attempting to connect to an IP and toggling them down forced them to look to the lagg0 interface for connectivity.